# Refresh other frame, from another frame. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, reload

Is it possible to reload the page, where the user came from or, even better, reload the frame the user came from, if it matches an URL?

I have a link. The user clicks it, and it opens in a new window, a new url. A form will run in that new window. What I want, is a function to reload the first window (Where the user came from)

Is that possible?

Comment: parent.frame_name.location.reload();

Comment: But the parent frame, is not an iFrame. So how would it look then?

Answer (score 2):

Alright. Here is what you do (just an example, tested, works):

test.html

```
<frameset cols="50%, 50%">
<frame name="f1" src="frame1.html">
<frame name="f2" src="frame2.html">
</frameset>
```

frame1.html

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="Refresh" onclick="parent.f2.location.reload()">
```

frame2.html

```
<span>Hello World</span>
```

variable `parent` is the parent of the current frame.

Read this [page](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpt/jstdg_ch13/index.html?page=7). its really helpful

Hope that helps

Comment: To the OP and Gasim; I'd just like to note, for future reference, that framesets have been removed from the HTML 5 spec (http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/, section 3.5 "Absent Elements")

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible *if you open another window*
It would however be possible if you just use some kind of overlaying frame like [jqmodal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

the README should give you the necessary instructions: http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/README

Answer (score 0):

How about loading the hyperlink url in the same page and redirect the user to the parent page after the form update is done.