# refresh one frame from another frame

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am using asp.net mvc3.visual studio2010.

I have three frames in my application. I want to refresh another pane, when I click the button in different pane.

For this, I used `frameset` in my application. I used like

```html
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%"> 
    <frame name ="f1" src="../SearchCriteria/Index"/> 
    <frame name="f2" src="../SearchResults/Index" /> 
    <frame name="f3" src="../SearchProfile/Index" />
</frameset>
```

When I am debugging the application, empty page is displaying in my output. Can you tell where I did mistake?

My view path is:
View->SearchCriteria->Index.cshtml View->SearchResults ->Index.cshtml View->SearchProfile ->Index.cshtml

Comment: for my application, I have three panes ,I want to refresh one pane,when i click the button on another pane.So initially i used iframes to load the content in the panes but refreshing one page from other page is not possible in iframes ,so i have moved to frameset.is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: I'd tackle this with JS and AJAX calls, using a library such as jQuery for providing the compatibility layer across different browsers.

Comment: I have a doubt,is it possible to use frameset in vs2010,and can u tell me how to refresh one pane from another pane ?

Comment: I think the last time I used frames was back in 1997 or so, I frankly don't remember all the details but AFAIR all you need to do is to set the `target` attribute on your form that posts the search. That said, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the server side; that you're using VS2010 and MVC3 is irrelevant.

Comment: actually in my application,i have left-pane,center-pane and right-pane in my splitter.In middle -pane i habe a button called"details",when i click on the button the right-pane has to refresh.my requirement like this way,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981349/refresh-other-frame-from-another-frame-jquery

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14894/discussion-between-steve-and-lucero)

Comment: Its urgent for me,can u please help me,how to solve this,I want to refresh one frame ,when user clicks the button in another another frame

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an ASP.NET MVC app, You should already have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in your project. Why not use some jQuery cool features and provide a wonderful user experience to users ?

Use DIVs, instead of FrameSet. Include jQuery library to this page ( or the Layout page so that it will be available in all pages that uses that layout template)

```
<div id="divNavigation">
  <ul>
     <li>@Url.ActionLink("About","About","Home",null, new { @class="lnk"})</li>
     <li>@Url.ActionLink("Contact","Contact","Home",null, new { @class="lnk"})</li>
     <li>@Url.ActionLink("Jobs","Jobs","Home",null, new { @class="lnk"})</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $(".lnk").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
     });
  });
</script>
```

What the above code does is, Whenever users click on an anchor tag with css class lnk, It will use the jQuery `load` function to load the content of the HREF page of the link in an asynchronous way. So there is no page refresh/reload , user will see.

Answer (score 0):

change frames to divs with ID,  on frame 1 have a button with ID, attach click event to button that will fetch data and populate the html of div 2, this is how it is done.  you will find that developers will go easy routes these days, code less and do more.   if your frames solution is possible ( I am sure it is )  it will be something that i am sure most developers would just gasp at, and go OMG WTF   why dident he just do  XXXX  and make this stuff easy to maintain :-)

I don't want to push any particular framework, but you can do all this with straight up javascript and return back html content, if you are not comfortable with JSON or XML.