# Session timeout in Java

Tags: java, jsp, html-frames

im using html page as my home page after login. i have set session timeout in web.xml. after session get timedout the login page is displaying only in one frame, but it should suppose to display in all frames..
Any idea how to acheive this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: what does session timeout has to do with frames? Please rephrase your question or add a little code so that we can get what you want to accomplish.

Comment: im having problems with frames

Comment: I suppose the OP is using a `<frameset>`. On session timeout, the login page is (of course) only shown in the current frame. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514666) for fixing.