# Putting scrollbar at the top instead of a frame

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I have two frames in a page. The height of one of the frames is fixed. When the other frame's height is bigger than the window size, a scrollbar appears and scrolls the frame only. but I want to scroll the whole page, not just a frame. Is that possible?

I've added a screenshot below. I want to scroll both two frames when the Frame2 exceeds the window size.

[image: frames]

Comment: Can you show us example markup?

Answer (score 1):

First  of: [Why should I not use HTML frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203068/why-should-i-not-use-html-frames)

So you should try using a different approach instead of frames. Unless you have an overwhelming reason to keep using frames.

Comment: I know a different approach would be better but I just want to know is there a way to do this.

Comment: Been playing around with it and couldn't find a way, sorry.