# Is it a website with frames and framesets well designed?

Tags: html, frame, frameset

I'm working on a webpage and I'm using frames. I'd like to make it using tables, but I don't know how to implement each part of the frame into a table.

So, my question is, is it well designed? If not, how can I improve it?

Here is the code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Prueba
        </title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="56px, *, 50px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
        <frame class="header" src="header.html">
        <frameset cols="450px, *" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
            <frameset rows="*,150px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
                <frame class="frame1" scrolling="auto" src="search_results.html">
                <frame class="frame2" scrolling="no" src="info.html">
            </frameset>
            <frame class="frame3" scrolling="no" src="map.html">
        </frameset>
        <frame class="footer" scrolling="no" src="footer.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203068/why-should-i-not-use-html-frames

Comment: @ŠimeVidas No one. I see them the best way to do what I have to do. The problem when the frames must interact between them. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Garmen1778 What exactly makes them the best choice for you?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas The width and height of each frame are easily editable, and I need that. I don't know ho to do it with tables.

Comment: @Garmen1778 You can use CSS `width` and `height` to define the dimensions of your elements on the page.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Can I edit the CSS of a single column or a row of a table? How?

Comment: @Garmen1778 You assign ID values to the main structural elements of your page. And then you use ID selectors for your CSS rules: `#leftcol { width: 450px; }`

Comment: The question does not appear to be constructive. The poster ased essentially the same question again after about an hour, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589097/how-to-put-this-code-into-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start improving it by removing frames.

- Frames have been obsolete for a long time and have been removed completely in HTML5.
- They're are better ways of accomplishing a common layout using server side technology like PHP includes or SSI.
- Plus frames are not good for accessibility or usability.
- They are not search engine friendly
- They break the rule of one URL fer page
- They are not easy to maintain. It can be tough to figure out exactly which page you are viewing.
- Mobile devices probably are going to have a hard time rendering those pages properly.
- Users can't bookmark a page since every page uses the same URL