# How to put this code into a table?

Tags: html, frame, frameset

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Prueba
        </title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="56px, *, 50px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
        <frame class="header" src="header.html">
        <frameset cols="450px, *" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
            <frameset rows="*,150px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
                <frame class="frame1" scrolling="auto" src="search_results.html">
                <frame class="frame2" scrolling="no" src="info.html">
            </frameset>
            <frame class="frame3" scrolling="no" src="map.html">
        </frameset>
        <frame class="footer" scrolling="no" src="footer.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I want to remove all frames and rebuild it with tables. I tried to dosomething, but I don't get the result that I want.

Comment: So what did you try?  We're more here to help with problems and less here to do this for you.  Also, unless you are laying out tabular data, you should do this with CSS and divs, not a table.

Comment: Frames to tables, a bad idea.

Comment: 2001 called. They want their [question back.](http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/layout/frames_or_tables/)

Comment: A) Use divs and css, B) abort project. Please choose an answer that best fits your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<table>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Prueba
        </title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="56px, *, 50px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
        <frame class="header" src="header.html">
        <frameset cols="450px, *" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
            <frameset rows="*,150px" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO">
                <frame class="frame1" scrolling="auto" src="search_results.html">
                <frame class="frame2" scrolling="no" src="info.html">
            </frameset>
            <frame class="frame3" scrolling="no" src="map.html">
        </frameset>
        <frame class="footer" scrolling="no" src="footer.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
</table>
```

There.

---

But serious. You don't want to use tables for layouting. Neither should you use frames.

The way to go would be to use divs. Or the new HTML5 elements.

Some new elements added to HTML are:

**Sections elements**

- section
- nav
- article
- aside
- hgroup
- header
- footer
- address

**Grouping elements**

- figure
- figcaption

Some benefits when not using tables for your layout:

- tables render slower
- tables don't work too well when using a fluid design
- tables are not the correct semantic elements to use for layout
- tables are for tabular data
- tables aren't really flexible if you want to change your layout at some point

Please note that when you want to use the new HTML5 elements you should set the correct doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also note that 'older' browser (and IE) don't know the new elements. To fix this issue you could add this simply JS script in the head of the document:

```
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('footer');
  document.createElement('time');
</script>
```

---

What you would get is something like the following:

**CSS**

```
​#body { width: 960px; }
aside { width: 450px; float: left; }
.content { margin-left: 450px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
    <header>
        <h1>Your header</h1>
    </header>
    <aside>
        <p>Aside</p>
    </aside>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>    
    <footer>
        <p>Your footer</p>
    </footer>
</div>    ​
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGPAW/

Comment: I wanted to replace the frames by tables. I asked it wrongly.

Comment: @Garmen1778 , how about you actually learn something that is not 10 years out of date ?

Comment: @tereško Something helpful for this? HTML5?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replicate the functionality of frames using tables. If you have a reason to rebuild the site, it is best to start from scratch, including decisions on functionality, general layout, and server-side technology used.