# Insert one HTML file into another HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a huge website, with on all pages a navbar.
Is it possible to create the navbar in a .html file and import it into all the other pages,
and if so, how?

Comment: Are you making it in php. If yes, then create a header.php and include it in all your pages like include 'header.php'

Comment: Yes if you're using php then use include keyword.

Comment: This is not a free _do your work_-site. Show some effort.

Comment: Not with HTML alone but yes you can with JavaScript (jquery)

Comment: Well, you can in theory use `<iframe>`. But it's not elegant and prone to design problems.

Comment: @popnoodles I did add a warning. There are worse things than that, believe me. And server side was never mentioned here, so it's not a correct dupe.

Comment: "Is it possible to create the navbar in a .html file and import it into all the other pages" OP doesn't know the term Server Side Includes, they just know what they want, which is Server Side Includes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Out of interest can you tell me what worse ways there are than using frames to include common content?

Comment: @popnoodles I don't mean in this specific topic, just worse things web developer can do with a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with PHP it's possible, but you have to change the files to .php files.

put this in the main file:

```
<?php 
     include("navbar.php");
?>
```

I don't know a *good* way with HTML

Comment: I'll change to php than, If that's the only *good* option.. thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

**You can do this with HTML alone** using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). Simplest example:

**index.html**

```
<html><head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    <!--#include file="navbar.shtml" -->
</body>
</html>
```

**navbar.shtml**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

What you should never do is use framesets or iframes to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15938545/822711

Please note, **this will not work using the `file://` protocol, it needs to run on a web server** as it would in a live environment. This could be on a private or public server, or localhost using a server running on your computer such as [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Comment: The link you posted refers to frames, not the HTML tag `<iframe>`. While not ideal it's not really that bad for a simple site.

Comment: I'm sorry, using any type of frame to load navigation is a horrendous idea for any site no matter how simple.

Comment: Before give this answers have you checked it ?Please give a full example.Your code is not working!

Comment: @user3085661 my code is not working where? On your localhost? On some random server? Did you read the wiki? Is your server set up to recognise SSI? "Is not working" is not a valid description of the problem

Comment: @user3085661 best guess is you're trying to run **server side** code while opening the page as `file://`. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: This is new to me. include shtml file in a comment tag.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer try to use Jquery,Like as

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(function(){
      $('.header').load("header.html"); 
   });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In same folder open a file with name `header.html`.Same thing you can apply for footer.

Comment: Just so you know, answers that suggest using jQuery to do something simple that can easily be done at root level often get marked down.

Comment: where suggest ?It's the ans I know so why I will not answers?

Comment: You're introducing a client-side framework to do something that is easily achievable server side, and works far better done server side. No FOUC, no extra page load, no extra framework.

Comment: If he want to convert it in server side he have to convert file type,like as .php etc.In here he don't need to change anything without this small code.

Comment: *"If he want to convert it in server side he have to convert file type,like as .php"* No he/she doesn't. HTML can be included in HTML.

Comment: Please give a full example in your answers.I want to see how it is working.Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SSI+html

Comment: This way to load html inside another html works...but that is very slow. Can you suggest some other way ? This way make page very slow.

Answer (score 4):

1) In html we can load other files into one html file using  **Iframe**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="header.html">
  <p> display</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

2) We can use jquery function to load the file into some specific div.

```
 <script> 
    $(function(){
        $('#header').load("header.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

3) Use other languages like php , .net for that
   we use php **include** and **require** for that

```
**Apart from using iframe there is no other way in html that we can include one html file to another.**
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to add server side language if you are using PHP you can create a
nav.php file. In this file you can add the complete HTML of your navigation and you can 
include this PHP file in your code instead of putting navigation HTML.
Like this

```
<?php include("nav.php");?>
```

Comment: Formatting. No PHP ever mentioned.

Comment: Why are you putting full answer to code tags?!

Comment: I mentioned .php extension.@Shadow Wizard is that any way to include file in HTML?

Comment: @RizwanSultan there are other server side languages out there, not only PHP. Besides, your whole answer is just unreadable block of code, proper answer should be formatted. I would do it myself but no point if you're not willing to spend that little extra effort to do that yourself.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard thanks buddy now I add some more details it's bit confusing formatting in Stackoverflow I just start using it.But Hope I will learn formatting standards.

Comment: It's really not hard to format, thousands of people are doing it just fine every day... anyway others have done it for you.