# Effectively Including one html file in another html file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a file, **a.html**, and a css file, **a_style.css**, that is linked to a's `<head>`. I  now want to include a second html file, **b.html**, which has its own style included in the `<style>` tag. Specifically, **b.html** specifies the footer I want in **a.html**. My question is: The **a_style.css** file defines the headings, margins, etc. which also apply to **b.html**. If I include **b.html** in **a.html**, does **a_style.css** still apply to the included file? Further, the following is all I have to include **b.html** in **a.html**:

```
<div class="footer">
<?php include('./project/b.html');?>
</div>
```

Is this enough? Or do I need to include something in a's `<head>`, similar to

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

(this particular code comes from MathJax)? I have no prior knowledge of php and found this snippet on a similar question: [Insert one HTML file into another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868304/insert-one-html-file-into-another-html-file?lq=1).
This has not yet worked for me. I tried changing the extension to .php, but then the eclipse editor does not allow me to collapse/expand individual tags any longer, making the script very messy.

Comment: have you tried to rename your files to `.php` instead of `.html`?

Comment: yes. this has not worked. Besides, it causes eclipse to not show  me the expand/collapse feature any longer...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to include html code the php command `include` is not the right tool. As mentioned in a comment it's used to include PHP code. You just want to read a file and print it out. So what you want to use is `readfile`

```
<div class="footer">
<?php readfile('./project/b.html');?>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter where the CSS / JS includes are. Most people include them in the `<head>`-Tag, others like to do it at the end of the `<body>` tag. But if you want to make this work it, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

> The **a_style.css** file defines the headings, margins, etc. which also apply to **b.html**. If I include **b.html** in **a.html**, does **a_style.css** still apply to the included file?

Let me start by saying that it all depends on  *where you are including your file*. Conflicting styles will be overridden by whichever comes last. Let me explain how.

Suppose you have three files:

- a.php
- a_style.css
- b.php

**Scenario: 1**

When you include **a_style.css** *after* including **b.php** in your **a.php** file:

**a.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page A</title>

    <?php

        require_once("b.php");

    ?>

    <link href="a_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <p>This is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**a_style.css**

```
p{
    color: #00ff00; /* green */
}
```

**b.php**

```
<style>
    p{
        color: #0000ff; /* blue */
    }
</style>
```

Output:

[image]

Since we have included **a_style.css** after **b.php**, hence **a_style.css** will override every conflicting styles(in this case paragraph color), hence the green colored paragraph.

**Scenario: 2**

When you include **a_style.css** *before* including **b.php** in your **a.php** file:

**a.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Page A</title>

    <link href="a_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <?php

        require_once("b.php");

    ?>

</head>

<body>

    <p>This is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**a_style.css**

```
p{
    color: #00ff00; /* green */
}
```

**b.php**

```
<style>
    p{
        color: #0000ff; /* blue */
    }
</style>
```

Output:

[image]

Since we have included **a_style.css** before **b.php**, hence **b.php** will override every conflicting styles(in this case paragraph color), hence the blue colored paragraph.