# What is the best way to set URL for <frame> in <frameset>

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset

I'm working with **frameset** and **frame** right now and I'm so confused about how to change frame URL. My customer they using either **location** or **src** wherever they like to set/change frame URL. Sometime **location** work, sometime **src** work so I'm going to find out what's going on.
I create 3 html files: *parent.html*, *left.html*, *right.html*. Here is the *parent.html* content

```
<frameset cols="*,*">
   <frame id="left" src="left.html">
   <frame id="right" src="right.html">
</frameset>
```

Here is the *left.html* content

```
<head>
    <script>
        function LocationThis() {
            window.frames['innerleft'].location = "http://prntscr.com";
        }
        function SrcThis() {
            window.frames['innerleft'].src = "http://prntscr.com";
        }
        function LocationOther() {
            window.parent.frames['right'].location = "http://prntscr.com";
        }
        function SrcOther() {
            window.parent.frames['right'].src = "http://prntscr.com";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Left</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="LocationThis();">Location this</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="SrcThis();">Src this</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="LocationOther();">Location other</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="SrcOther();">Src other</button>
    <hr/>
    <iframe id="innerleft" src="" />
</body>
```

Only **src** work in this case. Then why **location** work sometime but **src** won't? Ok, now I change script like this

```
//window.parent.frames['right'].location = "http://prntscr.com";
window.parent.frames[1].location = "http://prntscr.com";
```

Then **location** work fine. So **frames['right'].src** and **frames[1].location** then. But not all the case, sometime **frames['right'].location** work too. When I remove id and only using name for frame I must use **location**

```
<frame name="right" src="right.html">
```

That's it. Oh and thanks to IE refuse to take src so I must checking like this

```
try {
  window.parent.frames["id"].src = {url};
}
catch(er) {
  window.parent.frames["id"].location = {url};
}
```

Is there a neat solution for this whole things?

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203068/why-should-i-not-use-html-frames

Comment: Well this project like 10 years ago. I'm dealing with IE 5, frameset... can't convince them to change

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually confirm this, because on Chrome it doesn't even work (check out de [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) on the `window.frames` object), but I am assuming that getting the frame by ID will return a reference to the HTML element, which has a `src` property - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame

And when you do it properly (getting by index), you get a reference to the `window` object of that frame, which has a `location` property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

So, my guess is that `window.frames['id'].src` works in some cases because of some quirk browser implementation, but in reality your options are:

1. `window.frames[index].location`
2. `document.getElementById('FrameID').src`

Comment: May be you run with file:///. **window.frames[index].location** become a mess with 3-4 frames. Get by ID is the best choice except they're not working in IE < 8 so I must add a try catch...